# Plot each clusters in different colors Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, cluster-analysis

I have a data A set with 100 rows and 2 features. Firstly, I need to plot the dataset .

```
 plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'.');
```

Then I run the fcm clustering :

```
[center,U,objFcn] = fcm(A,2)
```

After running FCM clustering, I need to plot this data with each cluster has particular color with the marks as centers.  Is there any way to plot like that ?

Comment: `plot(data(logicalMatrixOfFeature1)); hold on; plot(data(logicalMatrixOfFeature2));`?
Try to be more specific what you want. Plotting in different colors is trivial as plot itself will keep changing color, custom colors are answered many times here already. Help with filtering of data is impossible until you tell us what the data even is. Filtering might be as simple as `A>x` or require `kmeans` or similar.

Comment: To answer your literal question, yes. There is.

Comment: Sometime I just feel bad for the guys who write the doc, check this [link](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fcm.html#buv_wo_-4)

Comment: It seems that can plot well the data after clustering. However, the plot of original data ( before clustering) and the plot with centers ( after clustering ) are different . Why ? Could anyone can help to plot the original data and the data after clustering please ?

Comment: How to plot the example in your link in 3 or 4 clusters ?